# Representing a matrix as a product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have a 4x4 matrix of complex numbers, say $X$ and I want to represent it as a product of a 4x1 & 1x4 vectors $x$ such that $$X = xx^H$$ where H denotes hermitian transpose of $x$. I am unsure how to proceed with this problem. Any hint/suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if and only if $X$ is a rank one Hermitian positive semi-definite matrix (or if $X$ is the zero matrix). If $X$ is of rank one, you can find a unit length column eigenvector $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ of $X$ with $Xv = \lambda v$ and $\lambda > 0$. Then $X = (\sqrt{\lambda} v) \cdot (\sqrt{\lambda} v)^H$.

Comment: I see. but the rank of the matrix is 4 & it isn't positive semi-definite (Matrix X in matlab is given as X = [0.4079 + 0.0000i 0.7532 + 0.0030i 0.9791 + 0.0272i 0.9335 - 0.0036i;0.7532 - 0.0030i 1.2288 + 0.0000i 1.3074 + 0.0052i 0.9791 + 0.0272i;0.9791 - 0.0272i 1.3074 - 0.0052i 1.2288 + 0.0000i 0.7532 + 0.0030i;0.9335 + 0.0036i 0.9791 - 0.0272i 0.7532 - 0.0030i 0.4079 + 0.0000i].Any suggestion on finding a solution for these kind of matrices?

Comment: Then you can't represent $X$ as $X = xx^H$. You can try to approximate $X$ using the best possible rank-one matrix $uv^H$ - this is related to the SVD decomposition (you can read about it in Wikipedia).

Comment: How did you get the final result? Did you multiply both sides by $v^H$? Is it always true that $vv^H$ is the identity?

Comment: If $v$ is a unit-length vector, then $v^Hv = 1$ and $vv^H$ is a rank-one matrix for which $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ (because $(vv^H)(v) = v(v^Hv) = v$).

Comment: Oh yeah, that's clear. Thanks!

Comment: I have applied SVD algorithm as you suggested to the mentioned problem and have obtained the values of $uv^H$. But $uv^H$ is a rank 3 matrix and I am not able to understand how to obtain $x$ from it! Any suggestion?

Comment: If $u, v$ are columns vectors than $uv^H$ is a rank one matrix. The vectors $u$ and $v$ should be the left and right singular vectors that correspond to the highest singular value.

Comment: Yes but since the matrix $X$ that I want to decompose is 4x4, u and v aren't column vectors; they are matrices of dimension 4x4; so I am still not getting your point on how to obtain $x$.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do but if you are interested in low rank approximation of a matrix, you should read about how it's done using SVD and maybe ask questions separately.